# Updating database based on selected check boxes

Tags: c#, linq

I posted the original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41554920/1646540), but I think it would be nice to have someone else's eye on this code for improving it.

```
public override void Update(UserProfileDto item)
{
    base.Update(item);

    var memberIntersestIds = _memberInterestService.GetAllPlusDeleted();

    var dbIds = memberIntersestIds.Select(p => p.InterestSubCategoryId);
    var union = dbIds.ToList().Union(item.InterestIds);

    if (item.InterestIds != null)
    {
        var guids = union as Guid[] ?? union.ToArray();
        foreach (var id in guids)
            if (_memberInterestService.IsSubInterestExist(id))
                _memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, true);

        foreach (var id in guids)
        {
            if (!_memberInterestService.IsSubInterestExist(id))
                _memberInterestService.Add(new MemberInterestDto
                {
                    UserProfileId = item.Id,
                    InterestSubCategoryId = id
                });
            else
                _memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, false);
        }
    }
    else
        foreach (var memberInterest in memberIntersestIds)
            _memberInterestService.Delete(memberInterest.InterestSubCategoryId, item.Id, true);
}
```

**MemberIntersetService**

```
public class MemberInterestService : IMemberInterestService
{
    public IQueryable<MemberInterest> Items { get { return _dbSet.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false); } }

    public MemberInterestService(AppDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
        _dbSet = dbContext.MemberInterests;
    }

    public bool IsSubInterestExist(Guid subInterestId)
    {
        return _dbSet.Any(p => p.InterestSubCategoryId == subInterestId);
    }

    public bool IsSubInterestExistInItem(Guid subInterestId)
    {
        return Items.Any(p => p.InterestSubCategoryId == subInterestId);
    }

    public void Delete(Guid interestId, Guid userProfileId, bool delete)
    {
        var item = _dbSet.Single(x => x.InterestSubCategoryId == interestId && x.UserProfileId == userProfileId);

        //soft delete
        item.IsDeleted = delete;

        _dbSet.Update(item);
    }

    public IList<MemberInterestDto> GetAllPlusDeleted()
    {
        return _dbSet.Select(x => Mapper.Map<MemberInterest, MemberInterestDto>(x))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's actually an interface that contains some method to perform operation against `MemberInterest` @denis

Comment: `bool IsSubInterestExist(Guid subInterestId);
bool IsSubInterestExistInItem(Guid subInterestId);
void Delete(Guid interestId, Guid userProfileId, bool delete);
IList<MemberInterestDto> GetAllPlusDeleted();`

Comment: Where are the selected check-boxes?

Comment: @t3chb0t I get them from user as `IEnumerable<Guid>` (item.InterestId)

Comment: You need to rethink the title.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi I would suggest to add all of the necessary types, so reviewers can test, as it's unclear why you have a `bool` parameter in your `Delete()` method and why this makes things different. Also there might things to improve to your existing classes. Code size wont scare us.

Comment: @t3chb0t I did my best believe me, If you think it's not a proper title, please help me to edit it thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### OMITTING CURLY BRACES ?

Don't do that a single line statements like this are acceptable even tho they are still not recommended you should always have `{}` :

```
if (Foo is Bar)
    return "Foo is Bar";
else
    return "Foo is not Bar";
```

But this is a huge red flag for bad code style :

> ```
> foreach (var id in guids)
> {
>     if (!_memberInterestService.IsSubInterestExist(id))
>         _memberInterestService.Add(new MemberInterestDto
>         {
>             UserProfileId = item.Id,
>             InterestSubCategoryId = id
>         });
>     else
>         _memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, false);
> }
> foreach (var id in guids)
>     if (_memberInterestService.IsSubInterestExist(id))
>         _memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, true);
> ```

If your statement needs to be written on few lines You should have `{}` e.g in your `foreach` as it's body contains more than a single line, same goes for your if's it's kinda hard to read it that way and follow the flow of your program.

Aside from that I would move `dbIds` && `union` inside your `if (item.InterestIds != null)` as you are performing potentially unnecessary operations, they will be used only if the if is triggered anyway :

```
if (item.InterestIds != null)
{
    IEnumerable<Guid> dbIds = memberIntersestIds.Select(p => p.InterestSubCategoryId);
    IEnumerable<Guid> union = dbIds.ToList().Union(item.InterestIds);
    Guid[] guids = union as Guid[] ?? union.ToArray();
    //..
}
```

This line I assume you have because you are avoiding multiple enumeration

> ```
> Guid[] guids = union as Guid[] ?? union.ToArray();
> ```

But why not call `.ToArray()` on `union` instead, there is no need to create new variable here, you are always working with `guids` and never using `union` itself as `IEnumerable<>` :

```
IEnumerable<Guid> dbIds = memberIntersestIds.Select(p => p.InterestSubCategoryId);
IEnumerable<Guid> guids = dbIds.ToList().Union(item.InterestIds).ToArray();
```

This part of your method :

> ```
> foreach (var id in guids)
> {
>     if (_memberInterestService.IsSubInterestExist(id))
>     {
>         _memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, true);
>     }
> }
>
> foreach (var id in guids)
> {
>     if (!_memberInterestService.IsSubInterestExist(id))
>     {
>         _memberInterestService.Add(new MemberInterestDto
>         {
>             UserProfileId = item.Id,
>             InterestSubCategoryId = id
>         });
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         _memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, false);
>     }
> }
> ```

It's weird, and so is the `.Delete()` method. First you have a `foreach` that remove duplicates from the database

> ```
> foreach (var id in guids)
> {
>     if (_memberInterestService.IsSubInterestExist(id))
>     {
>         _memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, true);
>     }
> }
> ```

But apparently you don't trust your methods and you keep searching if there is any item that exist in your db with a matching ID from the set you've previously iterated and already removed. What's the point ?

But why you deleting the items from the db only the first time ? What's different ? It's the same ID collection.

Since there is no obvious reason why are you doing this, I would suggest to combine those in a single `foreach` :

```
foreach (var id in guids)
{
    if (_memberInterestService.IsSubInterestExist(id))
    {
        _memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, true);
    }
    else
    {
        _memberInterestService.Add(new MemberInterestDto
        {
            UserProfileId = item.Id,
            InterestSubCategoryId = id
        });
    }
}
```

With all of those changes your code should  look like this :

```
public void Update(UserProfileDto item)
{
    MemberInterestService _memberInterestService = new MemberInterestService();
    IList<MemberInterestDto> memberIntersestIds = _memberInterestService.GetAllPlusDeleted();

    if (item.InterestIds != null)
    {
        IEnumerable<Guid> dbIds = memberIntersestIds.Select(p => p.InterestSubCategoryId);
        IEnumerable<Guid> guids = dbIds.ToList().Union(item.InterestIds).ToArray();
        foreach (var id in guids)
        {
            if (_memberInterestService.IsSubInterestExist(id))
            {
                _memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, true);
            }
            else
            {
                _memberInterestService.Add(new MemberInterestDto
                {
                    UserProfileId = item.Id,
                    InterestSubCategoryId = id
                });
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var memberInterest in memberIntersestIds)
        {
            _memberInterestService.Delete(memberInterest.InterestSubCategoryId, item.Id, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Your `Delete` method might be better of with a `.FirstOrDefault()` instead  of `.Single()` unless you really want to verify there is exactly one item, `.FirstOrDefault()` should be faster in most cases as it will return whenever the first item is found, where `.Single()` will always be O(n) operation because it needs to verify if there is exactly one occurrence.

Probably more can be improved, but again more context is required.

Comment: _But apparently you don't trust your methods_ my favourite part ;-)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions :) If possible please take at look at [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41554920/1646540)

Answer (score 2):

Please Simplify this and only do this in one foreach loop. I didn't see any reason that you needed to have 2 foreach loops here

> ```
>     foreach (var id in guids)
>         if (_memberInterestService.IsSubInterestExist(id))
>             _memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, true);
>
>     foreach (var id in guids)
>     {
>         if (!_memberInterestService.IsSubInterestExist(id))
>             _memberInterestService.Add(new MemberInterestDto
>             {
>                 UserProfileId = item.Id,
>                 InterestSubCategoryId = id
>             });
>         else
>             _memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, false);
>     }
> ```

you should only have to iterate over the `guids` once like this

```
foreach (var id in guids)
{    
    if (_memberInterestService.IsSubInterestExist(id))
    {
        _memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, true);
    }   
    else
    {
        _memberInterestService.Add(new MemberInterestDto
            {
                UserProfileId = item.Id,
                InterestSubCategoryId = id
            });
    }
}
```

I also used proper indentation and used Curly Brackets ***Everywhere*** because otherwise it is unclear, at quick glance, what is going on in the nested if statements.

I also removed the else that was setting the Delete value of the item to false (soft delete)  although I am not sure what the purpose of "Delete" really is, you do not make it clear that you are not actually deleting anything.

I am not sure what is real in your code...

Comment: When will the `else` even be triggered ?

Comment: I think OP should add  more context and more types to the question so a proper review can be done.

Comment: I am not sure what the third parameter means in `_memberInterestService.Delete(id, item.Id, false);`

Comment: @Malachi It's like a toggle delete, by setting true, it deletes the item from the database;`IsDeleted = true`